# Dynamically updated apple touch icon not working

Tags: javascript, html, ios, iphone, safari

I'm building a website that can have a custom favicon src URL - specified in another app. When visiting the website, I want to display the apple touch icon as the favicon in that src URL.

If I hardcode the apple-touch-icon in the head like this, it works:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="https://my-favicon-storage.com/favicon.png">
```

[image]

But if I dynamically update like this, it doesn't work:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="data:,">


const appleTouchIcon = document.querySelector("link[rel~='apple-touch-icon']");
appleTouchIcon.href = customFaviconSrc; // "https://my-favicon-storage.com/favicon.png" - custom favicon src configured in another app
```

[image]

The key point is: The apple touch icon URL has to be set with JavaScript, since I have no way to pre-render the index.html, it's a React app.

How can I make this dynamically set apple touch icon work??

Comment: What do you mean, _"specified in another app"_? What's the connection between that app, and the website, supposed to be?

Comment: @CBroe Updated the question. There is no connection between them other than one providing the favicon src URL for the other.